# How do I check whether debug mode is enabled?

Tags: 8

I enabled the Twig debug mode in the *development.services.yml* file. Is it possible to verify when the debug mode is enabled, using the `Twig_extension` class?

I need to check this in a Twig extension I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a [`Twig_Environment`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21twig%21twig%21lib%21Twig%21Environment.php/class/Twig_Environment/8.2.x) object to the extension method, it's possible to use [`Twig_Environment::isDebug()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21twig%21twig%21lib%21Twig%21Environment.php/function/Twig_Environment%3A%3AisDebug/8.2.x), as in the following example code.

```php
public function myfunction(\Twig_Environment $env, $string) {
  if ($env->isDebug()) {
    $string = 'foobar';
  }

  return $string;
}
```

Starting from Drupal 8.5.x, the `\Twig_Environment` class has been replaced from the [`Environment`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21twig%21twig%21src%21Environment.php/class/Environment/9.3.x) class. The previous code needs to be replaced by the following one.

```php
// Put the following line on the top of the file containing this method.
use Twig\Environment;

public function myfunction(\Environment $env, $string) {
  if ($env->isDebug()) {
    $string = 'foobar';
  }

  return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$twig_debug_on = \Drupal::service('twig')->isDebug();